# Apache forwared REMOTE_USER to php for SSO with NTLM

Tags: php, apache, single-sign-on, ntlm

I have to use NTLM for SSO in an Apache and PHP environment.
So I setup NTLM and the apache webserver to used it for SSO with this module **auth_ntlm_winbind_module**.

Apache Config:

```
<Directory "/var/www/www/html/current/public_html/">
  AuthName "NTLM Authentication"
  NTLMAuth on
  NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
  NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
  AuthType NTLM
  require valid-user
</Directory>
```

This works quite well, my user will be used for the authentication and I can access the website and I see myself also in the logs.

```
MY-DOM\\user
```

But I need to forwared this user to php because this website has an extra login form.

I tried with this configuration but had no luck

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-User %{ENV:REMOTE_USER}e
```

So what can I do to forward the REMOTE_USER variable to php?

Apache version is 2.4.6 (CentOS).

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks alot.

Comment: And did you solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we now use kerberos for SSO.